How to create an LTI system out of this?
I'm given the following system \$H\$ $$y(t)=\exp\left(-\intop_{-\infty}^{\infty}x(\tau)\cdot e^{-|t-\tau|}d\tau\right)$$ I proved it's TI (time-invariant) and that it's not linear.
Now we take as input \$y(t)\$ and we pass it through \$H_2\$, we are asked to construct \$H_2\$ such that the combination of \$H\$ and \$H_2\$ will be an LTI system.

When passing a linear combination of x signals through \$H\$ I get the following:
$$\exp\left(-{\displaystyle \intop_{-\infty}^{\infty}}ax_{1}\left(\tau\right)e^{-\left|t-\tau\right|}\right)\cdot\exp\left(-{\displaystyle \intop_{-\infty}^{\infty}}bx_{2}\left(\tau\right)e^{-\left|t-\tau\right|}d\tau\right)$$
In comparison to passing each part of it through \$H\$ and then multiplying each by the coefficients and adding them together
$$a\cdot\exp\left(-{\displaystyle \intop_{-\infty}^{\infty}}x_{1}\left(\tau\right)e^{-\left|t-\tau\right|}d\tau\right)+b\exp\left(-{\displaystyle \intop_{-\infty}^{\infty}}x_{2}\left(\tau\right)e^{-\left|t-\tau\right|}d\tau\right)$$
And this is where I'm stuck, I don't know how to get from all this information (from the question and my calculations) if a system \$H_2\$ is possible or not, and if it's possible I don't know how to derive it.

Need to see an attempt at a solution, Use Fourier  transform  equivalents

@VoltageSpike we've yet to learn about using the Fourier transform, it's the first practice  exercises paper we have since learned about systems just yesterday

System responses and LTI systems QA's also fit dsp.stackexchange.com section btw.

\$H_2=0\$ linearizes any system and makes it also time-invariant. This is not really a joke answer– in the end you're being asked to find a solution to a system of differential equations, and this is one particular solution.
Now, more productively: Let's start with the easy part, the nonlinearity. I'd say pretty intuitively, the \$\exp\$ ruins our day there. What counteracts an \$\exp(…)\$? Right, an application of \$\ln\$: \$\ln(\exp(u))=u\$, and \$u\$ is a constant multiple of \$u\$, so this is linear. If \$u\$ itself is linear in its input, then linear of linear is still linear. \$u(x(t))=-\int\limits_{-\infty}^{\infty}x(\tau)\cdot e^{-|t-\tau|}\mathrm{d}\tau\$, in this case, and we can test:

Homogenity: \$u(\alpha\cdot x)=-\int\limits_{-\infty}^{\infty}\alpha x(\tau)\cdot e^{-|t-\tau|}\mathrm{d}\tau=-\alpha\int\limits_{-\infty}^{\infty}x(\tau)\cdot e^{-|t-\tau|}\mathrm{d}\tau=\alpha\cdot u(x)\$, cheeeeck,
Additivity: \$u(x_1 + x_2) = u(x_1)+u(x_2)\$ (same calculation. Simply works because the integral is a linear operation.)

So, yeah that thing is linear.
Now, about the time variance: I'll leave this up to you, but I think your proof of time invariance might have room for improvement :) compare this integral with the convolution integral. You're just convolving \$x(t)\$ with \$e^{-\lvert t \rvert}\$

I did think of ln of course but in my head, it doesn't work, even taking your example of Homogeneity: if the input signal is ax then the output after H is the exp of the integral you wrote, but then with exponent rule,s you can bring it to the form of e^a * e^(the integral) and then passing that through a ln gives us the output a+(the integral) which is different then what you expressed

correct me if I'm wrong, but $\ln(\exp(\alpha u)) = \alpha u \ne \alpha + u$. You applied the ln twice, maybe?
